# How do I read the version number of an .exe inside a zip archive?

Tags: c#, reflection, zip

I have a zip file that contains an exe, and I want to get the version number of the exe file without having to extract it physically.

I know how to read the contents of a zip file, and have code that will read a text file in it, but I can't find out how to get the version of an exe.

Comment: So now you have the contents of the dll as a `byte[]` in memory?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I could get it that way I suppose. When I've done this before, I was reading text files, but I don't see any reason why I couldn't read a byte[] instead. How would that help though? I couldn't find any way to get the version number even then. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Add reference to Shell32.dll -library. <strike>Then you'll likely find what you are looking for with this:</strike>

```
 Shell shell = new Shell();
 var folder = shell.NameSpace( <path_to_your_zip> );

 // Just get the names of the properties
 List<string> arrHeaders = new List<string>();
 for (int i = 0; i < short.MaxValue; i++)
 {
   string header = folder.GetDetailsOf(null, i);
   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
     break;
   arrHeaders.Add(header);
 }

 // Loop all files inside the zip and output their properties to console
 foreach (Shell32.FolderItem2 item in folder.Items())
 {
   for (int i = 0; i < arrHeaders.Count; i++)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}: {2}", i, arrHeaders[i], folder.GetDetailsOf(item, i));
   }
 }
```

EDIT: Seems that this is not possible without actually extracting the file from the package. Something like this is fairly simple, but will take time in case the file is large and/or efficiently compressed.

```
Shell s = new Shell();
var folder = s.NameSpace( <path_to_your_zip> );

foreach (FolderItem2 item in folder.Items())
{
  string oItemName = Path.GetFileName(item.Path);

  try
  {

    string oTargetFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), oItemName);
    if (File.Exists(oTargetFile))
      File.Delete(oTargetFile);

    Folder target = s.NameSpace(Path.GetTempPath());
    target.CopyHere(item, 4);

    var info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(oTargetFile);

    if (File.Exists(oTargetFile))
      File.Delete(oTargetFile);

    Console.WriteLine(oItemName + "'s version is: " + info.FileVersion);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  { 
    Console.WriteLine(oItemName + ": Unable to obtain version info.\n" + e.Message);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's a great bit of code. Unfortunately, it doesn't show the version number. It shows type, compressed size, ration, etc, but no version number. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry to hear it didn't work. I did some more googling and it seems getting the version info is not possible if the file is not extracted first. Edited the answer to provide best method in my knowledge to do so.